# How to create gray 8bit CGImage from CIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, avcapturesession, core-image

I'm currently working on iOS application that uses front camera to capture frames. I want to compare actual frame with previous frame. In order to make that fast I want to create 8bit grayscale CGImage.

I'm using AVCaptureSession and I have implemented delegate:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    let image = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)).imageByApplyingOrientation(5)
    let img = context.createCGImage(image, fromRect: image.extent(), format: kCIFormatBGRA8, colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray())
}
```

But this gives me crash with description that this color space is unsupported. Do you have any advice how I can create 8bit grayscale CGImage fast?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't know the answer to your question, but are you aware there's a CIFilter that does difference blending:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIDifferenceBlendMode

It *may* be of use in your project.

Simon

Comment: Thanks for this advice, but it won't help me. I have my own image processing algorithm, but first i need to convert image to grayscale.